# React : функциональные компоненты или классы

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

Какие компоненты лучше использовать, в каких случаях, или лучше придерживаться одного вида компонент, или же использовать то , что удобнее? Не вижу разницы между ними, так как есть хуки, в  react я новенький, если это глупый вопрос , заранее прошу извинить , но дайте информацию пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это вопрос предпочтений, но react двигается в сторону хуков. Они проще, понятнее и нагляднее.